# Adding a column from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, copy

I am currently using asp.net membership provider and it has several tables as shown below!

[image]

And in this there are two main tables where the info of user is stored such as username,password,email etc..

Now I have password column in Membership table.So I would like to include a copy of that in the users table.

So how can I do that?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? It breaks the most basic rules of database design and if done badly can easily break data integrity.

Comment: So that's what I would like to know if it breaks completely then it's a bad idea so is there any other possibility to do that as I am not deleting it I need to copy it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe if we understood your real problem we could point you to a solution. You do not generally want to repeat data like this. Yes I could tell you how to do that but that would be irresponsible and unprofessional of me since I know what you want to do is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @HLGEM-Yeh I agreed with you too and drop the idea of copying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually creating a "password" field in the Users table and copying the content of the Membership table is not a good idea, as already pointed out by HLGEM in his comment.

If you really want to query the Users table **and** get the password from the Membership table in the same query, why don't you just join the tables?

```
SELECT aspnet_Membership.Password, aspnet_Users.*
FROM aspnet_Membership 
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
```

If you need this query really often, you can create it as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW YourUserView AS
SELECT aspnet_Membership.Password, aspnet_Users.*
FROM aspnet_Membership 
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
```

Comment: @Christian-Yes I agree with all of your comments and suggestions and try to acheive them as what you'll said.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against altering the schema as provided by MS at all.  If you find yourself in a situation where you need to call support and they find out that you did that, they are within their right to not help.